# Parse - saving public data for a specific user

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a table view of public posts that everyone can see with an upvote/downvote system (much like reddit). Whenever a user upvotes a post, the upvote arrow color changes to blue. How do I save that upvote data for a specific user so that when they close and re-enter the app, it shows the blue arrow displayed for them?